# How to invoke destructor when launching another page on flutter navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyNewPage()),
  )
```

This loads a new page.

How can I make it such that it calls a destructor on the current page so it can clear its things properly?

I tried adding a dispose method but it isn't executed when I change pages.

Answer (score 2):

**To clear whole current context you can use:**

```
 Navigator.of(context)
    .pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
     MyNewPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false)
```

Make sure to use a RoutePredicate, that always returns false `(Route<dynamic> route) => false`. In this situation it removes all of the routes except for the new `MyNewPage()` route pushed in stack.

**In case you need to execute some cleanup function**

- You can invoke it overriding [`dispose()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) method:
  it is called when this object is removed from the tree permanently. Keep in mind, that it is an error to call `setState` here and make sure to end your method with a call to `super.dispose()` when overriding it.

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  // Your function.
  super.dispose();
}
```

- You can invoke it overriding [`initState()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method of route you are pushing in a stack: It  is called when this object is inserted into the tree. If you override this, make sure your method starts with a call to `super.initState()`.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Your function.
}
```

- If you need a `BuildContext` for your cleanup function you can use [`didChangeDependencies()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html): It is called when a dependency of this State object changes and also immediately after `initState`, it is safe to use `BuildContext` here. Subclasses rarely override this method because the framework always calls build after a dependency changes. Some subclasses do override this method because they need to do some expensive work (e.g., network fetches) when their dependencies change, and that work would be too expensive to do for every build.

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Your function.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

**[Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package also has variety of ways to insert a Middleware function:**

- **Redirect** : This function will be called when the page of the called route is being searched for. It takes RouteSettings as a result to redirect to. Or give it null and there will be no redirecting.

```dart
GetPage redirect( ) {
  final authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
  return authService.authed.value ? null : RouteSettings(name: '/login')
}
```

- **onPageCalled** : This function will be called when this Page is called before anything created you can use it to change something about the page or give it new page.

```dart
GetPage onPageCalled(GetPage page) {
  final authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
  return page.copyWith(title: 'Welcome ${authService.UserName}');
}
```

- **OnBindingsStart** : This function will be called right before the Bindings are initialize. Here you can change Bindings for this page.

```dart
List<Bindings> onBindingsStart(List<Bindings> bindings) {
  final authService = Get.find<AuthService>();
  if (authService.isAdmin) {
    bindings.add(AdminBinding());
  }
  return bindings;
}
```

- **OnPageBuildStart** : This function will be called right after the Bindings are initialize. Here you can do something after that you created the bindings and before creating the page widget.

```dart
GetPageBuilder onPageBuildStart(GetPageBuilder page) {
  print('bindings are ready');
  return page;
}
```

- **OnPageBuilt** : This function will be called right after the GetPage.page function is called and will give you the result of the function. and take the widget that will be showed.
- **OnPageDispose** : This function will be called right after disposing all the related objects (Controllers, views, ...) of the page.

Comment: how would this work? Which code will be executed on the current activity on the dispose?

Comment: It disposes of the current context and removes all routes from the stack

Comment: I need some function to be executed, because I need to clean C++ resources held by this screen

Comment: And of course it creates new context from new passed route and pushes it at the stack as first and only route there. If you need to use named route- use .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()

Comment: It clears context so this is what you need

Comment: yes but how can I trigger some code before pushing to the new route?

Comment: I got you. Have a look at `Get` package. They have easy way to add middleware functions to routing. If you dont want to use get i will write you another way but when i will wake up)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Navigator.pushReplacement` as follows:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
```

this will push what you tell it and dispose the previous one once the new one finishes loading.