# Make a variable in build build context run once

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget which uses a provider to get questions. The question type looks like this:

```json
{
  "question": "What...",
  "answer: 1829,
  "buffer": [1928, 1874, 1825]
}
```

I have a shuffle method which shuffles the items passed to it. So in my widget, I have this code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var state = context.watch<Services>();
  Tion tion;
  List<int> shuffled;
  int selectedNumber;

  if (state.questions != null) {
    tion = state.questions[0];
    shuffled = shuffle([tion.answer, ...tion.buffer]); // here's my issue
  }

  return ...
}
```

Deeper in the widget tree, I render these numbers:

```dart
GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: List.generate(4, (index) => 
                  Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                        selectedNumber = shuffled[index]; // setstate
                      }),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: selectedNumber == shuffled[index] ? Color(0xff6C63FF) : Colors.grey[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10)
                          )
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '${shuffled[index]}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey[800]
                            )
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              )
```

The problem is when I call `setState()`, the widget rebuilds, and the order of the numbers along with it. Is there any way to prevent this? I tries with `initState` but it's called outside the scope of `context`.

Comment: If you need context you can try `didChangeDependencies` or one of the GetX callbacks https://stackoverflow.com/a/66463214/13701546

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this was a dumb question I'm new to flutter & dart. Go ahead and make this the answer, I'll verify it for you 

Comment: You are welcome, its actually not dumb question - you have to keep an eye on your widget dependencies, because if they change didChangeDependencies() will be called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `BuildContext` for your function you can use [`didChangeDependencies()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html): It is called when a dependency of this State object changes and also immediately after `initState`, it is safe to use `BuildContext` here. Subclasses rarely override this method because the framework always calls build after a dependency changes. Some subclasses do override this method because they need to do some expensive work (e.g., network fetches) when their dependencies change, and that work would be too expensive to do for every build.

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Your function.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

[Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package also has variety of ways to insert a Middleware function. You can check them on package page.

Comment: As does flutter_hooks.  "useEffect" is very cool.